# When creating a new data frame, how do I set the key labels to the numbers in a linespace np.array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am hoping to make a new data frame using several 1-d numpy arrays, one of which I would like to use as the key labels. I would like each existing array to represent one row. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.row_stack` before feeding to `pd.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
B = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
C = np.array([9, 10, 11, 12])

K = np.linspace(0, 1, 3)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.row_stack((A, B, C)), index=K)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

     0   1   2   3
0.0  1   2   3   4
0.5  5   6   7   8
1.0  9  10  11  12

print(df.loc[0.5])

0    5
1    6
2    7
3    8
Name: 0.5, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: I get the following error: "The shape of passed values is (71,10), indices imply (71,71)." My linespace function is just x = np.linspace(5.,75.,71), so I'm not sure why that implies a square matrix? Thanks again!

Comment: Please update your question with a **minimal** example.

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem. I'm trying to use my linespace array as my key values, not my indices. Will row_stack not work for that?

Comment: I figured it out! I used `df.columns = ...` Thanks again!